# citations in Medical Image Analsys template does not work with Latex compiler 2021/2020

Tags: citing, natbib, bibliographystyle

Citations in the Medical Image Analysis template do not work if I set the compiler version to 2020 or 2021. They render with questionmarks:
[image]

Reproducible example:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/mnpzcbykghbn

In my paper I use the tabularray package which seems to require a 2020 or newer compiler, so I cannot use the legacy compilers:
https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=de

In the template they use a .bst file to control display of the bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}
\bibliography{refs}
```

I tried replacing it with newer .bst files from the elsarticle package with no success:
https://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle?lang=de

Also setting `\bibliographystyle{authoryear}` does not help.

Link to to the template in case you don't want to download it from overleaf(search link for latex): https://www.elsevier.com/journals/medical-image-analysis/1361-8415/guide-for-authors

Comment: You shouldn't link to all sort of external files which will get obsolete over time but provide a small, complete example demonstrating the issue here. Beside this look into the log and the blg file if there are errors.

Comment: thanks for the warm welcome. There is a reproducible example on overleaf?

All the links I provided are context?

Comment: I restructured the post so people who don't read to the bottom can find the example easier.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please read the [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and try to provide a [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927). The links you provide do not help to understand your problem, since they only provide templates and classes but do not show your concrete problem. Therefore it is very hard to help you with only these general informations you provide. At least it is from my point of view.

Comment: Is the link to the example not accessible for you?

" Reproducible example: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mnpzcbykghbn "

Comment: It is. It's just not an MWE, which you have been asked to provide, in addition to being an external link, which is not particularly welcome on this site.

Comment: Okay I removed some clutter.

Comment: I am not sure how I could provide a working example here as Elsevier loads all these requirements.

Comment: In your main file on Overleaf, you need to include the bibliogpraphy (that is: `\bibliographystyle{model2-names} \biboptions{authoryear} \bibliography{refs}` right before `\end{document}`) in order to make the citations work. If I copy all necessary files and add these lines, all citations work with a current TeX installation.

Comment: I am totally confused about what is going on, this was in the original template before I started removing stuff. Apparently, I also deleted the bibliography in the process and did not notice because it continued rendering question marks. But it indeed works now in the MNWE. Apparently, I broke my MNWE by cleaning it up and made it a MWE.

Comment: Well this is one of the reasons why the best thing to analyse errors and bugs is to create a minimal working example: Remove code so that you can isolate the problem. One reason why everybody will ask you to provide a MWE here is that it will also help you to find the problem. In the end, of course, it will also help us to understand your code. So, I hope this bumpy start does not prevent you from using this site for future questions!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately we are dealing with Elsevier's legacy code.

To make it worse in my real document the solution is still not working, instead it just shows the first letters of the citations.

Comment: I managed to recreate the problem now it seems to be related to `\section*{\itshape Random name}` in line 118. To make it worse in my actual manuscript citations render but are displayed as single letters.

Comment: Hmm in my main manuscript this seems to be caused by an incompatibility of the elsevier template and `\usepackage{newclude}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line seems to cause the error in the rendering of references. Apparently, `\itshape` is not fully supported:

```
\section*{\itshape Random name}
```